# Replace semicolon with comma and add inverted commas in both end of a string in stored procedure to make it searchable in IN clause

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am very new to SQL query so, sorry If I miss basic details.
Here is the scenario:

I have to search the user email Id inside the column.

the column contains values like

```
abc@company.com;xyz@company.com;test@company.com;
```

Now I got the user email id from query:

```
DECLARE @emailid AS VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @emailid = emailId FROM dbo.tblUser WHERE userName  = 'abc' AND projectId ='P1456'
```

I also replaced the semicolon with a comma like:

```
COLUMNNAME IN (REPLACE(@emailid,';' ,','))
```

Now I got the string like `abc@company.com,xyz@company.com,test@company.com,`

But IN clause treat it as a single string, So how to append inverted commas in each email ids like below to help IN clause to search?

```
'abc@company.com','xyz@company.com','test@company.com',
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: You dont need to append anything, you would wanna search for a particular email from the string right

Comment: Are you really storing multiple email values in a singe column as a CSV? Not really a good design. And you now know why...

Comment: Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad), where you will see a lot of reasons why the answer to this question is  **Absolutely yes!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @emailid AS VARCHAR(50)
SELECT @emailid = 'abc@company.com;xyz@company.com;test@company.com;'

SELECT   @emailid AS emailid
        ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING( ''''+@emailid+'''', 
        PATINDEX(';',@emailid), 51),';',''+ ''''+','+''''+'') AS [replaced]
```

I hope you are using MSSQL